# Advantage of MPI_SEND over MPI_ISEND?

Tags: mpi

Using `MPI_SEND` (the standard blocking send) is simpler than using `MPI_ISEND` (the standard non-blocking send), because the latter should be used along with another MPI function to ensure that the communication has been "completed", so that the send buffer can be reused. But apart from that, has `MPI_SEND` any advantages over `MPI_ISEND`? It seems that, in general, `MPI_ISEND` prevents deadlock and also allows better performance (because the calling process can do other things while the communication proceeds in the background by MPI implementation).

So, is it a good idea to use the blocking version at all?

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, `MPI_Send()` has the potential of being faster that `MPI_Isend()` immediately followed by `MPI_Wait()` (and it **is** faster in Open MPI).

But most importantly, if your MPI library does not provide a progress thread, your message might be sitting on the sender node until MPI is progressed by your code (that typically occurs when a MPI subroutine is invoked, and definitely happens when `MPI_Wait()` is called).